# Database design for 'user' table in RDBMS

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, rdbms

I have to design a user table for an Edtech application having users with profile types.

Profile types are:

```
1. Student
2. Tutor
3. Teacher
4. Admin
5. School Admin
```

Now, I want to ask which is a better solution to model this type of user table. Each profile has some common attributes and some unique attributes.

The question is should I have separate tables for each type of user with a key mapping to the main user table having common fields

OR

Should I just separate the uncommon fields and place them into a table with the key mapping to the main user table?

Both these solutions will remove the nulls in the main user table. So, which one to go for?

Comment: Was discussed a million times already. In particular, here yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175248/create-a-database-table-where-entries-can-come-from-another-table-or-entirely-ne/51286016

Comment: This is different than the link you suggested. Please read again.

Comment: How is that different exactly? You're asking about how to move unique attributes away from the main table. Option 1 is correct - use individual extension tables that will be "glued" to the main table with a `JOIN` query. You can see it as this: main table is an abstract class and extension tables are implementing classes. Easy peasy :)

Comment: why is option 2 not correct? that I want to know. In option two also the same thing happens. Why is option 1 a better solution?

Comment: What's the point in having the second table in option 2? You'll still have NULLs in it. It solves nothing as far as I can tell.

Comment: you probably didn't get question. In the 2nd option, we create separate tables for uncommon fields and not the entire user type. So we do eliminate the nulls. Example, `qualification` is something which will be there for tutor and teacher and not for any other. So, instead of making tables for `tutor` and `teacher` we make a table for qualification, and similarly for other uncommon fields. This solution is practically doing the same thing but the names of the tables will be different. What is the advantage of having separate tables for user type?

Comment: The tables of uncommon fields will have keys mapping back to user table.

Comment: And then your query will look like `SELECT * FROM user JOIN qualification JOIN work_info JOIN hobby JOIN pet JOIN ...` ? Does not sound right to me.

Comment: See if we make separate tables for each user type then also it will be the same because it will be a one-to-many relationship between `tutor` and `hobby` and `tutor` and `pet`, correct? As I said, the joins will be the same, its just the name of the table.

Comment: No, the relation is supposed to stay one-to-one. You should only have common fields and unique fields, nothing more. So, you will always have it as simple as `user JOIN tutor`.

Comment: yeah i get that, but what about qualification and tutor, and hobby and tutor, and pet and tutor? These are in factmany-to-many relationship. One tutor can have many qualifications and one qualification can be passed by many tutors. Same way with hobby and pet. So, the number of joins remain the same weather you have separate tables for user_type or you have separate tables for uncommon fields. The answer, I think lies in access management.

Comment: This is a faq. Google re sql/database subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism.